# How to limit size of redirected stdout in exe4j

Tags: install4j, exe4j

We're using install4j/exe4j to create a windows launcher. We configure the redirection of stdout / stderr in Advanced Options / Exe4j Wizard - Redirection.

Is it possible to limit the size of the log generated? Or even better: something like the rolling file appender in log4j?

Regards,
Markus

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not a supported feature as of 6.1.4. If you produce a lot of output, you would currently have to use a logging system that includes those features.